# Ionic 4 - build as PWA, app runs and works with no errors but build fails

Tags: ionic4

I built my ionic 4 and ready for production.
no errors or warning when ionic serve,
but when I run Ionic build --prod.
these errors:

```
ERROR in src/app/baby/baby.page.html(6,9): : Property 'buttonIcon' does not exist on type 'BabyPage'.
src/app/baby/baby.page.html(5,9): : Property 'Back' does not exist on type 'BabyPage'.
src/app/baby/baby.page.html(22,14): : Property 'baby' is private and only accessible within class 'BabyPage'.
src/app/baby/feeding/feeding.page.html(6,9): : Property 'buttonIcon' does not exist on type 'FeedingPage'.
src/app/baby/feeding/feeding.page.html(5,9): : Property 'Back' does not exist on type 'FeedingPage'.
src/app/baby/feeding/feeding.page.html(27,3): : Expected 1 arguments, but got 0.
src/app/home/home.page.html(15,15): : Property 'babies' is private and only accessible within class 'HomePage'.
src/app/new-baby/new-baby.page.html(10,17): : Property 'babies' is private and only accessible within class 'NewBabyPage'.
src/app/new-baby/new-baby.page.html(21,9): : Property 'buttonIcon' does not exist on type 'NewBabyPage'.
src/app/new-baby/new-baby.page.html(20,9): : Property 'Back' does not exist on type 'NewBabyPage'.
src/app/register/register.page.html(11,13): : Property 'buttonIcon' does not exist on type 'RegisterPage'.
src/app/register/register.page.html(10,13): : Property 'Back' does not exist on type 'RegisterPage'.

That's some of the relavant code:
<ion-toolbar>
  <ion-buttons slot="start">
    <ion-back-button
        defaultHref="home"
        [text]="Back"
        [icon]="buttonIcon">
    </ion-back-button>
  </ion-buttons>
  <ion-buttons slot="secondary">
```

Comment: Plz share full code.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed the issue. turns out that the 
[text]="Back"
[icon]="buttonIcon"
is not necessary for the back button to work.
From some reason it is a part of the code snippet in the official ionic 4 documentation even though no such properties exist or needed. just removed them and it worked.

Comment: These properties are legit ones and documentation is correct. In your case you probably pointed those to nonexisting vars. It works for me and you can use those to customize back button details